# "Value error: Cannot use object with type int for spatial lookup parameter"

Tags: python-3.x, postgis, django-2.2

Added a Point field in one of my model to load map.to migrate the changes in model ,in pycharm terminal python manage.py makemigrations run okay. but python manage.py migrate raise ValueError('Cannot use object with type %s for a spatial lookup parameter.' % type(obj).**name**)
.

i think the reason could be changes in Django 2.2.I even tried using MultiPolygon field ,PointField .

settings.py

```
CORE_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'django.contrib.gis'
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

longitude = models.FloatField("Outlet Longitude", default=0.0, blank=False, help_text="Longitude")
    latitude = models.FloatField("Outlet Latitude", default=0.0, blank=False, help_text="Latitude")
    location = models.PointField()
```

i just want to load map .

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a problem that I entered the tuple value as the default value, so the error occurred.

1. Delete the migration information in the migrations folder of the model.
2. Set the default values as follows.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
location = gis_models.PointField(default=Point(0, 0), blank=True)
```

3. python manage.py makemigrations
4. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

To load the map using postgis you can do the following:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

location = gis_models.PointField(
        "Location in Map", geography=True, blank=True, null=True,
        srid=4326, help_text="Point(longitude latitude)")
```

Suggestion : Try using proper alias when importing models from a different app

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but still while i try to migrate it raise ValueError('Cannot use object with type %s for a spatial lookup parameter.' % type(obj).__name__)
ValueError: Cannot use object with type int for a spatial lookup parameter.

Comment: can you add the full error traceback in your question, that would be helpful